# Telerik Winforms UI: Showing UserControl-Forms tabbed and docked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, telerik

so far I have been using a standard winforms `TabControl` to host my different modules of my application statically, for example different GridViews. But this way the whole form becomes too big as it contains too many controls.

I would like to separate all the different "pages" each as a `UserControl` (from what I've heard, that's better than using `Forms`). Is that ok? And how is that best implemented with Telerik controls?

I thought about using a `RadDock` control and add my UserControls as `tabbedDocuments` to it.

```
DocumentWindow docWindow = new DocumentWindow();
MyUserControls.FirstGrid ctrl = new MyUserControls.FirstGrid();
docWindow.Controls.Add(ctrl);
radDock1.AddDocument(docWindow);
```

Is that ok to do? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Forms are very different compared to UserControls. I don't know exactly how you would like to separate the different pages of your application, but a UserControl always requires something to 'host' or display the UserControl in. A Form is a 'standalone window', basically.
2. Using the RadDock and tabbed documents is a valid way of doing it, but there a plenty of ways to separate different pages in your application, so I can't say which one fits best your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have two propositions for you:

1. If you decide to go with UserControls, you can use [RadPageView](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/pageview-stripview-getting-started.html) (or [RadDock](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-overview.html)) and on each RadPageViewPage (or DocumentWindow in RadDock) to add the UserControl in the Controls collection and show it.
2. You can use the Auto MDI functionality of RadDock and show your forms as MDI windows in it. More information is available [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dock-mdi-mode-automatic-mdi-form-handling.html).